# Symmetric 2x2 Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices

Consider the vector space $V= \{A \in \text{Mat}(2,2;\mathbb{R}) |  A^t = A \} \subset \text{Mat}(2,2;\mathbb{R})$ and the matrix 
$$L = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 \\0 & -2 \\ \end{pmatrix}\in\text{Mat}(2,2;\mathbb{R}). $$

How can I show that for $A \in V$ also $L^t \cdot A  \cdot L \in V$ and how do I calculate the determinant of the endomorphism

$f :V \rightarrow V, A \mapsto L^t \cdot A \cdot L$?

I know that obviously $$L^t= \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\2 & -2 \\ \end{pmatrix}$$ but I don't know how to advance from there.

Comment: To show $L^T AL \in V$, you need to show $(L^TAL)^T=L^TAL$. Hint: $(MN)^T=N^TM^T$.

Comment: Thanks. Now I have $(L^TAL)^T = (AL)^TL = L^TA^TL = L^TAL$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT** For your first question, whenever we have matrices $A,B$ of compatible dimension,
$$ (AB)^t=B^tA^t. $$
For your second question, observe that $L$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$, under the isomorphism
$$ A=\begin{pmatrix}a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{12} & a_{22} \end{pmatrix}\mapsto
\begin{pmatrix} a_{11} \\ a_{12} \\ a_{22} \end{pmatrix}.  $$
Using this isomorphism, we can write $f$ as a matrix, whose determinant can be readily computed.